# CCLabelTTF how to change color of string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, label

I am looking for a way how to change color of property string (which is actually title of label) of CCLabelTTF in Cocos2D framework and strangely I have not been able to find out how.

Any idea?

Comment: color works in all case....without code your question is invalid..

Comment: Please indicate wich Cocos2d framework version are you actually using, since it may differ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has color property.

```
    self.totalScoreText=[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"JFRockSolid" fontSize:font_ssz];
    self.totalScoreText.color= ccYELLOW;

    //Or
    self.totalScoreText.color= ccc3(100, 200, 200);

    //In cocos2d 3.0
    totalScoreText.color = [CCColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0.0];
```

Comment: So the string @"0" will be yellow? I though it is color of label.

Comment: you mean label background you want in different color? then why can't you simply draw colorLayer behind label ?

Comment: CCLabelTTF has a property named string, which represents title of the label, I wish to change the color of that title (property "string").

Comment: :) that's what .color property works. After setting .color = ccYELLOW not updated color of string in yellow?

Comment: The @Guru 's answer seems correct. Vanya, can you put your code as example? Are you wanting to change de color of one letter instead the whole label?

Comment: Sorry, that was bit my fault I was changing the color ( to white) in the other place as well and I wasn't aware of this. the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It has color property but .color is CCColor.
For example, It must be

```
self.totalScoreText.color = [CCColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the last version (Apr,2015) of the Cocos2d framework for ios, and according to the [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCLabelTTF.html), the color property for CCLabelTTF is `fontColor` :

`label.fontColor= [CCColor redColor];`

where `redColor` could be any other color, there are some constants included with the Cocos2d framework, type in black,blue,yellow,etc....

Good Luck.